# How to animate widget to new position on page transition?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I have a search bar widget that is in the center of the screen and when I click on the search bar, a new page is pushed using the Navigator. However on the page that is pushed on, the search bar is located at the top of the screen.

**My question is how can I animate the search bar from the center to the top of the page on Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...);**

The functionality I am trying to achieve is identical to that of the Google app. The search bar is in the center but when you click it, it animates to the top of the page.

I have taken a look at animated routes and AnimatedPositioned widget but they don't seem all too appropriate for this functionality. I'm not very familiar with animations in general so I really have no clue where to start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should try Hero widget. [Hero](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) animates widgets between two pages.

Here is example code from doc

```
class PhotoHero extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoHero({ Key key, this.photo, this.onTap, this.width }) : super(key: key);

  final String photo;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final double width;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      child: Hero(
        tag: photo,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Image.asset(
              photo,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrap both widget inside Hero and give same tag in bot pages.

Comment: The thing is the widget actually isn't the same. The centered search bar holds a simple text whereas the top search bar holds a textfield along with some icons. I tried this and the widget disappeared on page transition.

Comment: In that case, you can use page route builder to make custom page transitions to fit your liking. Reso Coder has an excellent tutorial for PageRouteBuilder https://youtu.be/C7CAMPdUu8o.